# Make own INTERNET WIFI web-based authentication page using WAMPSERVER

Tags: authentication, wampserver

i wondering, it is possible to redirect ALL WEBSITE to a URL(authentication page) in localhost (wampserver)..

after client login (in the authentication page) with correct ID and PASSWORD, then the client will be able to access to any WEBSITE.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, why? What are you actually trying to achieve

Comment: im actually trying to build a captive portal by using wampserver

Answer (score 0):

You could setup basic authentication in apache. Edit `httpd.conf` by clicking through from the WampServer icon and follow [these instructions](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth). However, instead of using `<Directory "/var/www/html/protected">` and doing it for each vhost, use `<Location />`. This is because each site will match that location directive so will all need to run the same authentication before sites will be shown.

If you didn't want to use basic auth in this manner, then I'd suggest you setting up shared authentication on your sites (like stack uses OpenID) or looking at something like [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), but that seems like a lot of work.

The final thing I'd point out is IP restriction. We have some clients/staff/etc that access our dev servers but it's all locked down to specific IPs and luckily so far everyone who's needed it has had a static IP. This may not be an option.